# Is there a way to schedule html changes?

Tags: html, css

Okay, I'm a bit of a newbie and know only quite basic html and css, so bear with me!

I have put together this calendar page: http://www.wondermagazine.co.uk/p/issue-2-november-2014_18.html

I have to go in and update it daily (with a specific thumbnail, a caption and a link). Is there a relatively easy way to activate certain HTML at specific days/times. So it can then become fully automated and I don't have to go in and make daily changes.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: This is what server-side processing (PHP, Ruby on Rails, etc.) is for.

Comment: Nope. This is why there are server side languages. You should take a look at Wordpress.org, that might be a direction to consider.

Comment: You could possibly do something like this with Javascript, but your best bet would be to look into server-side coding, or possibly a CMS based website software such as WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **no**.

Long answer: **Yes, of course.**  But you will either have to use a server side scripting language which generates your HTML for you and based on dates, will render different things, or, create a "dynamic" HTML page using a client side script such as Javascript.  Javascript allows you to create "live" pages, which can change their behaviour based on numerous variables, such as the current date time.

I believe you'll have to read up on these things.